# Selenium java code: How to read text from hidden element that contain many tags

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
1.<svg blablabla style:overflow: hidden  > <aaa id=aaa>
2.+
    3.<g>
    4.<g>
    5.<g>
    6.<g>
```

The  tags are inside the svg.
1 is the hidden tag, i want to get the 5th line text(), this is what i do.

```
WebElement hiddenDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("aaa"));
String n = hiddenDiv.getText();
String script = "return arguments[0].innerHTML";
n = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script,   hiddenDiv);
System.out.println(n);
```

how can i get g[2], i have tried by direct xpath and it got an error because the svg is hidden.

Comment: What is error you are getting??

Comment: n contains (NULL)...in the 5th line (<g) there is a text that i want to take.
n must contain this text.

i have changed the script:
    String script2 = "return   document.getElementsByTagName('g').innerHTML";

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('g')` gives array..so you need to provided index here like `document.getElementsByTagName('g')[2].innerHTML`

Comment: it's worked for me :) ... i have got this string :
<text fill="#222222" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" font-size="12" font-family="Arial" y="60.2" x="288" text-anchor="start">akkk</text>

i want just the text (akkk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to grab an array of the `g` tags and pick the one you want. If you want the 5th, you would use the code below.

```
List<WebElement> gs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#aaa g"));
System.out.println(gs.get(4).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: Webriver returns an empty string for invisible elements as a work around you can use getAttribute("innerHTML")

Comment: @dmr Thanks. I misread the question. If these elements are all hidden, they won't be found anyway so none of this will work. OP will have to use JSE to get them and get their text. I thought that only the first element was hidden. I didn't realize all the elements below were children and if the OP's code works, this should work. I'm confused... but maybe this will work anyway. :)